# Mobile.de Seller-API 406 Not acceptable error when posting ad

Tags: http, http-headers

I am trying to create a new Ad with Mobile.de Seller API.
I have credentials for a sandbox account that I use for the request. I think I setup everything correctly like authentication, X-Mobile-Insertion-Request-Id and Accept headers and also a sample JSON Ad object.

All other API calls like listing the sellers Ads work.

Except when creating an Ad I get

> 406 Not Acceptable

Currently I am using Postman to test the API requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I got no response to my question I am back with the answer.

The problem was the following header:

```
Accept: application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json
```

This header is used For GET-Requests. When performing Write-Requests such as POST and PUT you have to use following header instead of the 'Accept' header with same value:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json
```

That way the strange 406-Error is gone and the Ad gets created with a 201-created response.